# Java Running an exe not performing correctly

Tags: java, c++, opencv, exe

I'm running an openCV script that has a bunch of sliders, camera windows, etc  and I'm trying to call it in Java with the following script

```
try{

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
            Process p = rt.exec("C:\\Users\\Arhowk\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\x64\\Debug\\ProcessingManager.exe") ;
            InputStream in = p.getInputStream() ;
            OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream ();
            InputStream err = p.getErrorStream() ;  
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        (new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                for(;;){
                    try {
                    sleep(100);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

and the exec with the following script

```
//objectTrackingTutorial.cpp

//Written by  Kyle Hounslow 2013

//Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software")
//, to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, 
//and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

//The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

//THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
//FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER 
//LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
//IN THE SOFTWARE.

#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include "Processing.h"
using namespace cv;
//initial min and max HSV filter values.
//these will be changed using trackbars71,256,155,214
int H_MIN = 71;
int H_MAX = 256;
int S_MIN = 155;
int S_MAX = 214;
int V_MIN = 0;
int V_MAX = 256;
//default capture width and height
const int FRAME_WIDTH = 640;
const int FRAME_HEIGHT = 480;
//max number of objects to be detected in frame
const int MAX_NUM_OBJECTS=50;
//minimum and maximum object area
const int MIN_OBJECT_AREA = 20*20;
const int MAX_OBJECT_AREA = FRAME_HEIGHT*FRAME_WIDTH/1.5;
//names that will appear at the top of each window
const string windowName = "Original Image";
const string windowName1 = "HSV Image";
const string windowName2 = "Thresholded Image";
const string windowName3 = "After Morphological Operations";
const string trackbarWindowName = "Trackbars";
void on_trackbar( int, void* )
{//This function gets called whenever a
    // trackbar position is changed





}
string intToString(int number){


    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}
void createTrackbars(){
    //create window for trackbars


    namedWindow(trackbarWindowName,0);
    //create memory to store trackbar name on window
    char TrackbarName[50];
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "H_MIN", H_MIN);
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "H_MAX", H_MAX);
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "S_MIN", S_MIN);
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "S_MAX", S_MAX);
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "V_MIN", V_MIN);
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "V_MAX", V_MAX);
    //create trackbars and insert them into window
    //3 parameters are: the address of the variable that is changing when the trackbar is moved(eg.H_LOW),
    //the max value the trackbar can move (eg. H_HIGH), 
    //and the function that is called whenever the trackbar is moved(eg. on_trackbar)
    //                                  ---->    ---->     ---->      
    createTrackbar( "H_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &H_MIN, H_MAX, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "H_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &H_MAX, H_MAX, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "S_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &S_MIN, S_MAX, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "S_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &S_MAX, S_MAX, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "V_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &V_MIN, V_MAX, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "V_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &V_MAX, V_MAX, on_trackbar );


}
void create(int x, int y){
  std::ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("D:\\temp\\procio.txt");
  myfile << "x " << x << "\n";
  myfile << "y " << y;
  myfile.close();
}
void drawObject(int x, int y,Mat &frame){

    //use some of the openCV drawing functions to draw crosshairs
    //on your tracked image!

    //UPDATE:JUNE 18TH, 2013
    //added 'if' and 'else' statements to prevent
    //memory errors from writing off the screen (ie. (-25,-25) is not within the window!)

    circle(frame,Point(x,y),20,Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    if(y-25>0)
    line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x,y-25),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    else line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x,0),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    if(y+25<FRAME_HEIGHT)
    line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x,y+25),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    else line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x,FRAME_HEIGHT),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    if(x-25>0)
    line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x-25,y),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    else line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(0,y),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    if(x+25<FRAME_WIDTH)
    line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(x+25,y),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    else line(frame,Point(x,y),Point(FRAME_WIDTH,y),Scalar(0,255,0),2);

    putText(frame,intToString(x)+","+intToString(y),Point(x,y+30),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0),2);

}
void morphOps(Mat &thresh){

    //create structuring element that will be used to "dilate" and "erode" image.
    //the element chosen here is a 3px by 3px rectangle

    Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(3,3));
    //dilate with larger element so make sure object is nicely visible
    Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(8,8));

    erode(thresh,thresh,erodeElement);
    erode(thresh,thresh,erodeElement);


    dilate(thresh,thresh,dilateElement);
    dilate(thresh,thresh,dilateElement);



}
void trackFilteredObject(int &x, int &y, Mat threshold, Mat &cameraFeed){

    Mat temp;
    threshold.copyTo(temp);
    //these two vectors needed for output of findContours
    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    //find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
    findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
    //use moments method to find our filtered object
    double refArea = 0;
    bool objectFound = false;
    if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {
        int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
        //if number of objects greater than MAX_NUM_OBJECTS we have a noisy filter
        if(numObjects<MAX_NUM_OBJECTS){
            for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {

                Moments moment = moments((cv::Mat)contours[index]);
                double area = moment.m00;

                //if the area is less than 20 px by 20px then it is probably just noise
                //if the area is the same as the 3/2 of the image size, probably just a bad filter
                //we only want the object with the largest area so we safe a reference area each
                //iteration and compare it to the area in the next iteration.
                if(area>MIN_OBJECT_AREA && area<MAX_OBJECT_AREA && area>refArea){
                    x = moment.m10/area;
                    y = moment.m01/area;
                    objectFound = true;
                    refArea = area;

                }else objectFound = false;


            }
            //let user know you found an object
            if(objectFound ==true){
                create(x,y);
                putText(cameraFeed,"Tracking Object",Point(0,50),2,1,Scalar(0,255,0),2);
                //draw object location on screen
                drawObject(x,y,cameraFeed);}

        }else putText(cameraFeed,"TOO MUCH NOISE! ADJUST FILTER",Point(0,50),1,2,Scalar(0,0,255),2);
    }
}
void startProcessing()
{
    //some boolean variables for different functionality within this
    //program
    bool trackObjects = true;
    bool useMorphOps = true;
    //Matrix to store each frame of the webcam feed
    Mat cameraFeed;
    //matrix storage for HSV image
    Mat HSV;
    //matrix storage for binary threshold image
    Mat threshold;
    //x and y values for the location of the object
    int x=0, y=0;
    //create slider bars for HSV filtering
    createTrackbars();
    //video capture object to acquire webcam feed
    VideoCapture capture;
    //open capture object at location zero (default location for webcam)
    capture.open(0);
    //set height and width of capture frame
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_WIDTH);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,FRAME_HEIGHT);
    //start an infinite loop where webcam feed is copied to cameraFeed matrix
    //all of our operations will be performed within this loop
    while(1){
        //store image to matrix
        capture.read(cameraFeed);
        //convert frame from BGR to HSV colorspace
        cvtColor(cameraFeed,HSV,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        //filter HSV image between values and store filtered image to
        //threshold matrix
        inRange(HSV,Scalar(H_MIN,S_MIN,V_MIN),Scalar(H_MAX,S_MAX,V_MAX),threshold);
        //perform morphological operations on thresholded image to eliminate noise
        //and emphasize the filtered object(s)
        if(useMorphOps)
        morphOps(threshold);
        //pass in thresholded frame to our object tracking function
        //this function will return the x and y coordinates of the
        //filtered object
        if(trackObjects)
            trackFilteredObject(x,y,threshold,cameraFeed);

        //show frames 
        imshow(windowName2,threshold);
        imshow(windowName,cameraFeed);
        imshow(windowName1,HSV);


        //delay 30ms so that screen can refresh.
        //image will not appear without this waitKey() command
        waitKey(30);
    }
}
```

When I run the .exe via the VS2012 debug tool or via just double clicking it in Windows Explorer, it works fine and I'm able to do everything. When i do it in Java with the runtime, it works for anywhere from 50ms to 5 seconds than it says "ProcessingManager.exe has stopped responding" indefinitely. I can't figure out why its doing that so would anyone know

Comment: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: BTW - I am not so much surprised that code failed, but more that you ever thought it would work.  What resources are you reading as instruction?

Answer (score 0):

When starting using VC or double clicking the standard input and standard output of the executable file are different compared to starting using the Java "exec" method.

What you could do to find out if this is the problem is:

Create a **command-line based** executable (let's say it is named "testExecutable.exe") that simply contains an empty loop. You may use the "Sleep" Windows API function to ensure the program will not consume 90% of the computer's runtime:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    while(1) { Sleep(1000); }
}
```

Put this executable into the same directory as "ProcessingManager.exe".

Start the Windows command line (cmd.exe) and change to the directory where "testExcutable.exe" and "ProcessingManager.exe" are located.

Run the following command line:

```
testExecutable | ProcessingManager | testExecutable
```

If you are not aware with the command line window: The command window should look like this:

```
some_directory> C:
C:\some_directory> cd "\Users\Arhowk\Documents\...\x64\Debug"
C:\Users\Arhowk\...\x64\Debug> testExecutable | ProcessingManager | testExecutable
```

Now check if the program runs correctly. If not then the changed standard input and output are the problem.

You can kill the testExecutable.exe in the task manager (it is running twice) or by simply closing the Windows command line window.